# How do I add a bd model to a phylogenetic tree, I want to simulate it 1000 times to see number of species after 5 million years

Tags: r

I have a phylogenetic tree that I want to use to simulate speciation-extinctions to see how number of species are affected over time. I'm a student with only a little experience with R and I can't seem to get any of the functions to work.

I have tried using bd.ext, make.bd, fit.bd, and sim.bdtree functions but I keep getting errors. I just need a proper example of the script so that I can substitute in my phylo tree

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.